# Different results in debug mode and run mode c++

Tags: c++

I was testing my program in run mode and I was getting many formatting errors, so I went to debug mode to see what was happening, but for my surprise in debug mode, everything sees to work fine.
In Run Mode between the "Choose:" and the input there no space, Ii is printing the error message even before any input, etc.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string value;
    std::cout << "Choose: ";
    while(std::getline(std::cin, value))
    {
        if (value == "1" || value == "2" || value == "3" || value == "4" || value == "5")
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cerr << "Error! Choose a valid number." << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Choose: ";
        }
    }
}
```

Run Mode:

```
Choose:6
 Choose:Error! Choose a valid number.
6
Error! Choose a valid number.
 Choose:89
 Choose:Error! Choose a valid number.
6
 Choose:Error! Choose a valid number.
```

Debug Mode:

```
Choose: 6
Error! Choose a valid number.
Choose: 89
Error! Choose a valid number.
Choose: 
Error! Choose a valid number.
```

Comment: This question's shown code does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You should [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: please post a [mcve]. What is `value`?  What is `index` ? What is `RED` and `WHITE` ? With some creativity one can add missing parts to make your code do literally anything

Comment: @idclev463035818 already made the changes. Thanks

Comment: when I wrote "What is x? What is y? ..." this was just the most obvious holes in the fragment you posted. Adding the declarations only is still not a [mcve].

Comment: @idclev463035818 can't do much more, everything else for me seems essencial to figuring out what's happening in my code

Comment: why you can't do more? You must have code that you compiled to produce the output you report and that is not the code you posted. If you don't want to share the code, we cannot help you.

Comment: What's your proof that the problem must be here and not somewhere else in your program which results in undefined behavior, causing a massive amounts of [demons flying out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html), but the program continuing seemingly unaffected but at this point reality suddenly kicks in, and the previously-encounted bugs now result in random, garbage behavior? Just because the problem starts happening in this part of the code doesn't mean that's where the bug is. C++ doesn't work this way. The bug can be anywhere, which is why you must show a [mre].

Comment: @idclev463035818 so you're saying that I should add more code? But the error to my problem is happening under that while, every thing else is unecessary

Comment: If the rest of the code is unnecessary then delete it, compile your code, make sure your problem still exists then post that code as a [mre]

Comment: no I am not saying that you should post **more** code. Maybe read [mcve] again. minimal reproducible example does not mean: You know where the bug is and only show that part. As Sam points out: You do not know where the error is (would you ask otherwise?). Not only for asking here, but primarily for your own debugging you should isolate the problem in a small program that reproduces the problem and nothing else. What you need to make sure is to show us a complete code that we can compile and see the same result as you do. Telling you **where** the error is is for the answers then

Comment: @AlanBirtles the rest of the code is uneccesary because the problem is not happening in that part, i guess, but it doesn't mean that the rest of the code is not important for the all project

Comment: @qwerty156 can you reproduce the problem without that "unncessary" parts? No you cannot , because the code you did post will cause a couple of compiler errors that are not related to your question

Comment: @idclev463035818 got the point, Im gonna try to do that

Comment: I've tried to run the code you've posted, once I made it into a compilable example it didn't reproduce your problem, this is why we need a [mre]

Comment: @idclev463035818 i think now is good :)

Comment: @AlanBirtles could you retry now? I've made it as simple as I could.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik is it OK now?

Comment: as we already spend so much time on it I can also put my final nitpick: You are missing the includes.

Comment: Still can't reproduce any problems

Comment: me neither: https://godbolt.org/z/dse3q9. Do you get the output in the question with that code?

Comment: @idclev463035818 i dont know if it is important or not but im using clion, and the ouput that I get are the ones in the question.

Comment: I don't know what "CLion" has anything to do with anything. CLion is not a C++ interpreter. Once a C++ program is compiled, it is a binary executable, and nothing else matters. The code compiles and runs without any issues whatsoever. There is nothing wrong with the shown code.

Comment: I just want to say I'm sorry for all the rudeness you got here.